# usage of for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

I need to write program that will take first input as 'i' and this loop need to go 
until first input is less or equal to second input.
what I had written but seems not working:

```
function provjeri() {

    var i  = document.getElementById('prvi').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('drugi').value;
    var c = "";

    for (; parseInt(i) <= parseInt(b)  ; i+=2) {
        c+=i ;
    }

    document.getElementById('rez').innerHTML = parseInt(c);
}
```

Comment: e.g. first input is 3 secound input is 7, output is 3 plus 5 plus 7 equal 15

Comment: I don't think you can use a for loop like that. A for loop has a clear syntax which contains the declaration of the index to loop over. You should use a while loop. Additionally you are cancating strings rather than doing mathematics. Your result will be "357" not 15 because you define c as a string and then add a string to it.

Comment: You can use for loops like that, just don't see it used too often.

Comment: It is often viewed as more correct to use loops like that because it allows you to keep all your variable declarations in one place, usually the start of the function.

Comment: One possible issue is that you are using parseInt in your loop declaration for the first 'i' but not the second or the 'i' in the loop body. These will be treated as strings, as will c as it is declared using c="". There could be other problems also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseInt()` when getting the value. Also use `c=0`, `c=""` is considered as a string and new values are concatinated to `c`

```js
function provjeri() {
  var i = parseInt(document.getElementById('prvi').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('drugi').value);
  var c = 0;
  
  for (; i <= b  ; i+=2) {
    c+=i ;
  }
  document.getElementById('rez').innerHTML = parseInt(c); 
}
```

```html
<input id='prvi' />
<input id='drugi' />
<button onclick='provjeri()'>Calc</button><br>
<span id='rez'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
var k = 0;
var ival = parseInt(i);
var bval = parseInt(v);

for (k = ival; k <= bval; k += 2) {
   c += k;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should look like:

```
function provjeri() {
    var i  = parseInt(document.getElementById('prvi').value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('drugi').value);
    var c = 0;
    while(i <= b){
       c += i;
       i += 2;
    }
    document.getElementById('rez').innerHTML = c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are looking for this:

```js
function provjeri() {
    var i = document.getElementById('prvi').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('drugi').value;
    var c = 0; // needs to be a number
    i = parseInt(i, 10);
    b = parseInt(b, 10);

    for (; i <= b; i += 2) {
        c += i;
    }
    document.getElementById('rez').innerHTML = c;
}
```

```html
<input id='prvi'></input>
<input id='drugi'></input>
<button onclick='provjeri()'>call function</button><br>
<span id='rez'></span>
```

Comment: You also defined c as a string which makes it concat rather than add up. Edit: better now.

Comment: @Hotshot `0246` is it desired output, or it's error? just tried, snippet working fine